# "...has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "

Tags: angular, typescript, express

I'm having trouble displaying the API content in Angular and I don't know how to fix it to keep moving forward.
For now I just need to see the url data in my interface.
Does someone know how to solve this problem?
The civilizations file calls the get method created in game.service.ts

**civilizations.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GameService } from '../../services/game.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-civilizaciones',
  templateUrl: './civilizaciones.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./civilizaciones.component.css']
})
export class CivilizacionesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private gameService: GameService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.gameService.getCivilizations().subscribe(
      res => console.log(res),
      err => console.error(err)
    );
  }

}
```

**game.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'[![enter image description here][1]][1]
})
export class GameService {


  API = 'https://age-of-empires-2-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCivilizations(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.API}/civilizations`)
  }

  getCivilization(id: string){
    return this.http.get(`${this.API}/civilization/${id}`);
  }

  getUnits(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.API}/units`);
  }

  getUnit(id: string){
    return this.http.get(`${this.API}/unit/${id}`);
  }

  getStructures(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.API}/structures`);
  }

  getStructure(id: string){
    return this.http.get(`${this.API}/structure/${id}`);
  }

  getTechnologies(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.API}/technologies`);
  }

  getTechnology(id: string){
    return this.http.get(`${this.API}/technology/${id}`);
  }
}
```

[image: This is the error]

Comment: create a proxy.json and configure ur app to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue caused by the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). You can bypass this in dev mode by using the proxy config.

Your service:

```js
API = 'api/v1';
```

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
  "/api/v1": {
    "target": "https://age-of-empires-2-api.herokuapp.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

This will proxy any request that is `/api/v1/stuctures` to `https://age-of-empires-2-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/stuctures`.

To use the proxy run `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

Read more on using the [proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build)

> Note this will only work in development mode

Comment: Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Can I have problems using it in an HTML?